How to add a delete button to for swift data items?
I’m working on a macOS application. I have a list of SwiftData items. Something like this:
struct TestDataList: View {
    @Query var allTestData: [TestData]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Everything")
            if allTestData.count > 0 {
                List {
                    ForEach(allTestData){ test in
                        HStack {
                            Text(test.id)
                            Spacer()
                            Text(test.value)
                            Spacer()
                            Button("", systemImage: "trash", action: {
                                //  ?
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .modelContainer(for: TestData.self)
    }
}

I would like to add a button which will delete the current item.
I have searched around, but everything is for iOS, and I can’t see how it would apply here.
What action code do I need to delete the current item, both from the List, and, more importantly from the data?

You shouldn't add the .modelContainer modifier inside your views like you have done here and in previous questions. Most often you only need to do it once in the main App code.

Agree, that's what I showed in my answer to the previous question.
But I guess it was not acted on.

@JoakimDanielson I did that out of desperation. I have now removed the extra code. Thanks.

Try this approach, using modelContext and the TestData
to delete. Tested on real mac, MacOS 15.2 not Preview.
Note, no need for the if allTestData.count > 0 {
Here is the full code that works on macOS.
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TestDataList()
    }
}

struct TestDataList: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext // <--- here
    
    @Query var allTestData: [TestData]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // for testing, to add a few test data
            Button(action: addItem) {
                Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
            }.buttonStyle(.bordered)
            
            Text("Everything")
            List {
                ForEach(allTestData){ test in
                    HStack {
                        Text(test.id)
                        Spacer()
                        Text(test.value)
                        Spacer()
                        Button("", systemImage: "trash", action: {
                            modelContext.delete(test) // <--- here
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let randm = String(UUID().uuidString.prefix(5))
            let newItem = TestData(id: randm, value: randm)
            modelContext.insert(newItem)
        }
    }
}


@Model
class TestData {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: String
    var value: String
    
    init(id: String, value: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.value = value
    }
}

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var sharedModelContainer: ModelContainer = {
        let schema = Schema([
            TestData.self,
        ])
        let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)

        do {
            return try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
        }
    }()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(sharedModelContainer)
    }
}


Thanks, that’s what I ended up doing. However, I did find that the button triggered when I click anywhere on the list. I read somewhere that adding .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()) fixes that.

maybe you have your Button in a NavigationLink or something similar, but definitely does not happen with my code.
